# Como salvar Imagem em uma pasta especifica?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms, file-upload

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
protected void btnSalvarDestaque_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuFotos.HasFile)
    {
        string strname = fuFotos.FileName;
        fuFotos.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//Content/Destaques//" + strname);
        string path = "~/Content/Destaques/" + strname.ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Destaque values('" + txtTitulo.Text + "','" + txtValor.Text + "','" + strname + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblDestaque.Text = "Destaque cadastrado com sucesso!";
        txtTitulo.Text = "";
        txtValor.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblDestaque.Text = "Por favor selecione uma foto!";
    }
}
```

O cliente preenche os campos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O caminho é salvo no banco, e a foto teria que ser adicionada na pasta em questão que é Destaque:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que a imagem salva certinho no banco, mas não esta sendo adicionada na pasta e quando a página é executada aparece só isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou sabendo escrever o caminho certo, alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já obrigada! :D

Comment: Qual o caminho que aparece na página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quase que chegou lá, para corrigir basta altera da seguitne forma

```
protected void btnSalvarDestaque_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuFotos.HasFile)
    {
        string strname = fuFotos.FileName;
        string path = "~/Content/Destaques/" + strname.ToString();
        fuFotos.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Destaque values('" + txtTitulo.Text + "','" + txtValor.Text + "','" + strname + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblDestaque.Text = "Destaque cadastrado com sucesso!";
        txtTitulo.Text = "";
        txtValor.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblDestaque.Text = "Por favor selecione uma foto!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu brow, deu certinho!